# Python Booleans

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean, boolean-logic

In Python,

```
if 1 and 2 not in {0, 1}:  # return True
    print(True)
if 0 and 2 not in {0, 1}:  # return False
    print(True)
```

Don't know why can somebody please explain it to me?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence. `and` has lower precedence as `nat` and `in`

Comment: 0 is evaluated as false in python.

Comment: Try to understand *and* is short-circuit for first case, so if it see *1* ```Truth``` it will stop,  and the 2nd case it will continue to check after *or*...

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean:

```
if 1 not in {0, 1} and 2 not in {0, 1}:
```

The way you have it, it is resolving (if 1) and (if 2 not in {0, 1}
"If 1" always resolves to true.

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
mySet = {0,1}
if not all(x in mySet for x in (1,2)):
    print(True)

if not all(x in mySet for x in (0,2)):
    print(True)
```

Out:

```
True
True
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because that the `if` consists of multiple conditions. `1` is equal to `True` and `0` is equal to `False` and mostly, they can be used interchangeably.

So:

```py
1 and 2 not in {0, 1}
# is actually
(1) and (2 not in {0, 1})
# which equals to
(True) and (2 not in {0, 1})
# and both of them are True
True and True

# -------------------

# but in this case
0 and 2 not in {0, 1}
# is actually
(0) and (2 not in {0, 1})
# which equals to
(False) and (True)
# that is False
```

If you want to check if multiple values are in a sequence you should do this:

```py
1 in {0, 1} and 2 in {0, 1}
```